# Markitup custom bbcodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bbcode, markitup

I am trying to create a simple bbcode-enabled text-editor with just couple codes, but I need to create some custom codes and buttons for them such as [cut=#{line}]#{text}[/cut] and [talk]#{text}[/talk].
And I could not find any manual showing how to do that in markitup.

**UPDATE**

I'm using rails on server-side and I have already set up bb-ruby to treat those custom bb-codes safely, I just need to include them in the markitup setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a [BBCODE Set](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/downloads/demo.php?id=markupsets/bbcode)  and add your custom button to it.

The [documentation](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/documentation/) , section Magic Markups is explaining how to add and customize buttons.